# Recursively dropping elements from list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

Right now I'm working on a problem in Haskell in which I'm trying to check a list for a particular pair of values and return True/False depending on whether they are present in said list. The question goes as follows:

> Define a function called `after` which takes a list of integers and two integers as parameters. `after numbers num1 num2` should return true if `num1` occurs in the list and `num2` occurs after `num1`. If not it must return false.

My plan is to check the head of the list for `num1` and drop it, then recursively go through until I 'hit' it. Then, I'll take the head of the tail and check that against `num2` until I hit or reach the end of the list.

I've gotten stuck pretty early, as this is what I have so far:

```
after :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Bool
after x y z
    | y /= head x =  after (drop 1 x) y z
```

However when I try to run something such as `after [1,4,2,6,5] 4 5` I get a format error. I'm really not sure how to properly word the line such that haskell will understand what I'm telling it to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Edit 1: This is the error in question:

```
Program error: pattern match failure: after [3,Num_fromInt instNum_v30 4] 3 (Num_fromInt instNum_v30 2)
```

Comment: My mistake sorry, myTest is supposed to be `after`

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
after :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Bool
after (n:ns) a b | n == a = ns `elem` b
                 | otherwise = after ns a b
after _      _ _ = False
```

Basically, the function steps through the list, element by element. If at any point it encounters `a` (the first number), then it checks to see if `b` is in the remainder of the list. If it is, it returns `True`, otherwise it returns `False`. Also, if it hits the end of the list without ever seeing `a`, it returns `False`.

Answer (score 3):

```
after :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> a -> Bool
after ns a b =
  case dropWhile (/= a) ns of
    [] -> False
    _:xs -> b `elem` xs
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#dropWhile

Answer (score 2):

```
after xs p1 p2 = [p1, p2] `isSubsequenceOf` xs
```

So how can we define that? Fill in the blanks below!

```
isSubsequenceOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool

[] `isSubsequenceOf` _ = ?
(_ : _) `isSubsequenceOf` [] = ?
xss@(x : xs) `isSubsequenceOf` (y:ys)
  | x == y = ?
  | otherwise = ?
```

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood, the assignment didn't specify a function which determined if `a` was IMMEDIATELY after `b`, just if it was present in the list at some point after it. If so, then this solution answers the wrong problem.

Comment: @Kwarrtz, you seem to have confused subsequence with segment.

Comment: @dfuer, yes I suppose I have. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
   after :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Bool
   Prelude> let after xs a b =  elem b . tail $ dropWhile (/=a) xs
```

Examples:

```
  Prelude> after   [1,2,3,4,3] 88  7
  *** Exception: Prelude.tail: empty list
```

It raises an exception because of tail. It's easy to write tail' such that it won't raise that exception. Otherwise it works pretty well.

```
  Prelude> after  [1,2,3,4,3] 2  7
  False
  Prelude> after   [1,2,3,4,3] 2  4
  True
```